# how to initialize with zeros an array of undetermined size in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a method that receives a variable size array (*it can be any size*) and I need to add a counter at any position in the array.

Here is an example code with IRB

```
 ▶▶ irb
2.5.5 :001 > arr = Array.new(0)
 => [] 
2.5.5 :002 > max = rand(1..99)
 => 95 
2.5.5 :003 > count = rand(1..max)
 => 11 
2.5.5 :004 > arr[count] += 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from /home/elorat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.5/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
        1: from (irb):4
NoMethodError (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass)
2.5.5 :005 >
```

Comment: what exactly is your problem, you solved it but have the error above ?

Comment: `Array.new(rand(1..99), 0)` - will create array with random amount of values 0.

Comment: the problem I have is that the array variable is nil and does not allow me to use the `+=`

Comment: You can fill array with default values (0) before using it, or you can check for nil before incrementing value at specific index - your choice ;)

Comment: "the problem I have is that the array variable is nil" – In the code you posted, the array variable *cannot possibly* be `nil`. It is assigned an array and then never changed. There must be something else going on that you are not showing us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a 71% chance you are asking for this:

```
def increment_and_extend_if_necessary(arr, idx)
  arr.fill(0, arr.size..idx)      
  arr[idx] += 1
end
```

```
arr = []
```

```
increment_and_extend_if_necessary(arr, 3)
arr #=> [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

```
increment_and_extend_if_necessary(arr, 1)
arr #=> [0, 1, 0, 1]
```

```
increment_and_extend_if_necessary(arr, 5)
arr #=> [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

```
increment_and_extend_if_necessary(arr, 3)
arr #=> [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
```

See [Array#fill](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-fill).

Comment: @SimpleLime, thanks for the suggestion, a definite improvement.

Comment: I would have thought it was at most 70% chance.